# Where can i show the blob types in phpmyadmin? [xampp]

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I backuped and restored my database, now i see all the text fields as [BLOB - 5Bytes] but when i try to show them, i can see the values. Now how do i show them on the table view?

Comment: why need to view binary contents?

Answer (score 0):

On the page where its listing all my data for the selected table therer is a "+ Options". Click it and select that you want the BLOB Fields shown. My phpMyAdmin verison is 3.4.1